# Wordpress on NGINX opens white pages :(

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx

I developed some wordpress site on windows and there it worked fine without any problems. Now I need to migrate to Ubuntu 18.04 Server with Nginx and PHP 7.2 at board.

I do all by manuals, but any wordpress page are opens as blank white page :(
I tested it by adding to main folder phpinfo.php with phpinfo(); code and it opens without problems as domain/phpinfo.php, images and html files are also opens without problems as domain/image.png or domain/file.html.

The most awful thing is that I didn't get any errors :(

Here are my domain config:

```
 map $uri $blogname{
~^(?P<blogpath>/[^/]+/)files/(.*)       $blogpath ; }

map $blogname $blogid{
default -999;

#Ref: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/nginx-helper/
#include /var/www/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/nginx-helper/map.conf ; }

server {
server_name domain;

root /srv/domain;
index index.php;
access_log /var/log/nginx/domain.access.log;
error_log /var/log/nginx/domain.error.log;

location ~ ^(/[^/]+/)?files/(.+) {
    try_files /wp-content/blogs.dir/$blogid/files/$2 /wp-includes/ms-files.php?file=$2 ;
    access_log off;     log_not_found off; expires max;
}

#avoid php readfile()
location ^~ /blogs.dir {
    internal;
    alias /srv/domain/htdocs/wp-content/blogs.dir ;
    access_log off;     log_not_found off; expires max;
}

if (!-e $request_filename) {
    rewrite /wp-admin$ $scheme://$host$uri/ permanent;
    rewrite ^(/[^/]+)?(/wp-.*) $2 last;
    rewrite ^(/[^/]+)?(/.*\.php) $2 last;
}

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args ;
}

location ~ \.php$ {     fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;   fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
    try_files $uri =404;    fastcgi_index index.php;    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include fastcgi.conf;
}

#add some rules for static content expiry-headers here }
```

Here are my nginx.conf file:

```
user www-data; worker_processes auto; pid /run/nginx.pid; include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {    worker_connections 768; }

http {


ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE  ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;   error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

gzip on;

include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;   include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*; }
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Since phpinfo() and html pages are working. It could be the WordPress White Screen of Death (WSOD) issue.

- The WP_DEBUG feature often provides additional information.

May I know if you are able to access the wp-admin area?

```
https://www.domain/wp-admin
```

If yes, then try the following:

- A Plugin is causing compatibility issues. If you can access the
  Administration Screens try deactivating all of your Plugins and then
  reactivating them one by one. If you are unable to access your
  Screens, log in to your website via FTP. Locate the folder
  wp-content/plugins and rename the Plugin folder plugins_old. This
  will deactivate all of your Plugins. You can read more about manually
  deactivating your plugins in the Troubleshooting FAQ.
- Your Theme may be causing the problem. This is especially likely if
  you are experiencing the white screen of death after you have just
  activated a new Theme, or created a New Site in a WordPress Network.
  Log in to the Administration Screens and activate the default
  WordPress Twenty Sixteen Theme. If you can't access your
  Administration Screens, access your website via FTP and navigate to
  the /wp-content/themes/ folder. Rename the folder for the active
  Theme.
- Your Theme directory may be missing or renamed. This is common for
  developers who have just created a local development environment and
  cloned the database, which is pointing to a theme (or theme
  directory) that might be missing or renamed. To test this solution,
  try accessing wp-login.php or /wp-admin/. If you see anything, this
  is a good indication it's theme-related. Log in as an administrator,
  then try to view the front-end and you should see a WordPress error
  message to the effect of: The theme directory "{theme-name}" does not
  exist. You can solve this in any n umber of ways, including switching
  themes on the admin side, renaming your directory, or editing the
  "theme" and "stylesheet" records in wp_options

Source: https://codex.wordpress.org/Common_WordPress_Errors

Thank you!

Comment: Thanks for answer. No, /wp-admin didn't works as not works any wp page :( I defined in wp-config.php "define('WP_DEBUG', true);" , if I put "define('WP_DEBUG', false);" then even a white page does not open

Comment: is your wp-config setup with the new changes - it might not be able to find your database?

Comment: No, with DB connect all is ok. When I put wrong password to test it then I get "Error establishing a database connection", when I put correct password I get white page :(

Maybe I should install Ubuntu 16.04 and PHP 7.0 and try one more time?

Answer (score 0):

Installed apache2 alongside NGINX at the another port 8080 and problem still there :(

Images are opens, non wordpress php files opens, html opens, but Wordpress didn't open any page...

Comment: Rename your plugins folder. Every time I see a white screen it is a plugin causing the problem.

Comment: Yeaaaah brother! I caught error when renamed plugins folder. The problem was that php-curl was not installed.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I really appreciate your help